# BeautifulSoup4 parse everything except specific tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using python's [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to parse some HTML. The problem is I want to extract only the text of the document execept for `<ul>` and `<li>` tags. Sort of the opposite of [unwrap()](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#unwrap). Thus I want a function `parse_everything_but_lists` that will have the following behaviour

```
>>> parse_everything_but_lists("Hello <a>this</a> is <ul><li>me</li><li><b>Dr</b> Pablov</li></ul>")
"Hello this is <ul><li>me</li><li>Dr Pablov</li></ul>"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use `unwrap`, you just need to get a bit recursive.

```
from bs4 import Tag

def unwrapper(tags, keep = ('ul','li')):
    for el in tags:
        if isinstance(el,Tag):
            unwrapper(el) # recurse first, unwrap later
            if el.name not in keep:
                el.unwrap()
```

demo:

```
s = '''"Hello <a>this</a> is <ul><li>me</li><li><b>Dr</b> Pablov</li></ul>"'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(s, 'html.parser') # force html.parser to avoid lxml's auto-inclusion of <html><body>

unwrapper(soup)

soup
Out[63]: "Hello this is <ul><li>me</li><li>Dr Pablov</li></ul>"
```

This approach should work on any arbitrary nestings of tags, i.e.

```
s = '''"<a><b><ul><c><li><d>Hello</d></li></c></ul></b></a>"'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(s, 'html.parser')
unwrapper(soup)

soup
Out[19]: "<ul><li>Hello</li></ul>"
```

Comment: Didn't really work for me...
`a = bs4.BeautifulSoup('<td><a><a>s</a>k</a></td>', 'html.parser'); unwrapper(a); a =>
<a><a>s</a>k</a>` (didn't see the edit, w8 till i try that one)

Comment: Right, now it works! I cant post it right now but I could also get it to work by escaping the tags I want to keep and then make the result into BeautifulSoup. eg. `<ul>` -> `&lt;ul&gt;`